# Only use Browserstacklocal for certain URLs

Tags: automated-tests, protractor, browserstack

I'm currently trying to get my Protractor tests working with Browserstack. My (automated) tests are run on a staging server that can only be accessed from within a VPN. I am using Browserstacklocal to access the staging server without a problem.

My question: Is it possible to direct ONLY the staging server URLs through Browserstacklocal? For exemple, during my test, I go to PayPal Sandbox to purchase an item. I would like the Paypal connection to be made directly from the Browserstack remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-only" parameter restricts the Local Testing access to specified local servers and/or folders. Consider the following example:

./BrowserStackLocal ACCESS_KEY -only localhost,443,1

In this case, only the traffic for the domain “localhost” will be directed to your private server and rest all URL’s/domains will be accessed directly through our remote VM’s.
More details on all the Local Testing modifiers can be found [here](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#modifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Browserstacklocal's -only flag does the trick. Refer to [this article](https://www.surevine.com/restricting-browserstack-access-within-your-local-network/) for more info. Although I wouldn't mind someone explaining what the parameters are.

Comment: Documentation on different parameters supported by the Local Testing binaries is available [here](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#modifiers).